# How to pass/access node.js variable to an html file/template

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, fs

I am new to **Node.js** and I am trying to pass and access a variable from **Node.js** to a loaded **html** file/template, How do I achieve this?

Here is the sample code:

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <mate charest="utf-8" />
        <title>Hello world!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>User List</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Name: Name</li> <!-- how do I call the name variable here -->
            <li>Age: Age</li> <!-- how do I call the age variable here -->
            <br>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

**myService.js**

```
let fs = require('fs');
let path = require('path');

// How do I pass this variables to test.html
let age = 1;
let name = "this is name";

// Read HTML Template
let html = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "../core/pdf/test.html"), 'utf8');
```

How do I pass and access the **name** and **age** variable to **test.html** template so that when I read the file, the value of the variable is already generated in the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a express and a templating engine for this. Please refer templating engine list - https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library [handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars).
This one is very good to deal with larger templates.
In case you have to return a single tag, you can try this

```
return `<ul>
            <li>Name: ${name}</li>
            <li>Age: ${age}</li>
            <br>
        </ul>`
```

You can also consider using this template library for node.js
[npm-ejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs)

Comment: Hi @Omkar, Thank you very much. I got it working using [ejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs) .